# How to print this comparison operator?

Tags: symbols

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to look up a math symbol?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-math-symbol)

Does anyone know how to print this comparison operator (which looks like a combination of triangle and equal) between two operands?

[image]

Comment: Please have a look at this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-math-symbol I tried `Detexify` and it works.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: I tried, too, but `Detexify` didn't list this particular symbol. (Perhaps I'm simply bad at drawing, though.)

Comment: This symbol is provided by [`stmaryrd`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/stmaryrd) as `\trianglelefteqslant` and by [`mathabx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathabx) as `\trianglelefteq`.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: I could make DeTeXify give me the right symbol either.

Comment: `\trianglelefteqslant` actually isn't in Detexify. If you go to the [symbol table](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/symbols.html) and enter `triangleleft`, you won't find it among the results. The maintainer, however, isn't accepting symbol requests until the new version of Detexify is deployed. Nonetheless, `\trianglelefteqslant` can be found on page 40 of [The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://mirror.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf), hence my vote to close.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is `\trianglelefteqslant` from the [stmaryrd](http://ctan.org/pkg/stmaryrd) package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{stmaryrd}

\begin{document}

\Huge

\(\trianglelefteqslant\)

\end{document}
```

[image]